# No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionEvent

Tags: android, android-studio, greenrobot-eventbus

Why the debug was giving me this?
everything is works fine i just did not understand why Eventbus giving me this??

can someone please help me? so much thanks

it just bothering me that i have a problem with my codess

This is the Log.

> E/EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class
> com.creamydark.Izone.JoYuri.YuriActionMessage to subscribing class
> class com.creamydark.musilization.MainActivity
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar.selectTabInternal(BottomNavigationBar.java:530)
> at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar.selectTab(BottomNavigationBar.java:477)
> at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar.selectTab(BottomNavigationBar.java:467)
> at com.creamydark.musilization.MainActivity.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:455)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.dispatchOnPageSelected(ViewPager.java:1941)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:686)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:670)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
> at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
> at com.creamydark.musilization.MainActivity.eventMessage(MainActivity.java:204)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.invokeSubscriber(EventBus.java:510)
> at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:433)
> at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEventForEventType(EventBus.java:414)
> at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:387)
> at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:268)
> at org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus.postSticky(EventBus.java:309)
> at com.creamydark.musilization.BottomNavFragments.DetailSelectedAlphaFragment$1.onPostExecute(DetailSelectedAlphaFragment.java:111)
> at com.creamydark.musilization.BottomNavFragments.DetailSelectedAlphaFragment$1.onPostExecute(DetailSelectedAlphaFragment.java:106)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class
> org.greenrobot.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionEvent

This is my Subscriber from MainActivity.

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true )
    public void eventMessage(YuriActionMessage message){
        if (message.getAction() == "LOAD_PLAYER_UI") {
            load_ExoPlayerUI();
        } else if (message.getAction() == "LOAD_PLAYER_UI_PLAYPAUSE") {
            load_PlayPauseBtn();
        } else if (message.getAction() == "SET_CURRENT_VIEWPAGER_ITEM_DETAILFRAG") {
            mact_IzoneVIewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
            //EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(true);
        } else if (message.getAction() == "SET_CURRENT_VIEWPAGER_ITEM_ALBUMFRAG") {
            mact_IzoneVIewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            //EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(true);
        }
    }
```

This is the postEvent in my Fragment Attatch from MainActivity

```
public void initTrackModelList(long albumid){
        IzoneGetTracksByAlbum izoneGetTracksByAlbum=new IzoneGetTracksByAlbum(this.getActivity(),albumid){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                initRecyclerView();
                EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new YuriActionMessage("SET_CURRENT_VIEWPAGER_ITEM_DETAILFRAG"));
            }
        };
        izoneGetTracksByAlbum.execute(mTrackModel);
    }
```

this is my Event Message Model.

```
public class YuriActionMessage {
    private String Action;
    public YuriActionMessage(String action){
        this.Action=action;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return Action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Eventbus. Sometimes errors in your code are thrown as Eventbus exceptions. Check your code. For example:

```
 mact_IzoneVIewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
```